# Reshape a 3D array to a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a data frame of length `5800000` which is a concatenation of 100 files where each file has 58000 rows. I  have an array `fv` of shape  `(100, 10, 58000)` which I want to add to the data frame by adding 10 columns. `df` has a length of `5800000` with two columns but only focuses on the first column index, i.e `df.shape[0]`

```
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']  
fv = np.zeros(len(data), len(list_), int(df.shape[0]/len(files))
```

```
def add_fv_to_dataframe(_data, list_):
    for index in range(len(_data):
        for name_index, name_in_list in enumerate(list_):
            calculate something
            calcs_ = _data[index]
            fv[index, name_index, :] = calcs_
            # add the calculated values to the dataframe

            df['fv_{}'.format(name_in_list)] = pd.Series(fv.reshape(-1, (10,1)), index=df.index)
```

I would like to have my final data frame in the form;

| df[0] | df[1] | fv_a | fv_b | fv_c | fv_d | fv_e | fv_f | fv_g | fv_h | fv_i | fv_j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| : | : | : | : | : | : | : | : | : | : | : | : |
| 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 | 5800000 |

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.swapaxes`:

```py
for i, data in enumerate(np.swapaxes(fv, 0, 1)):
    df[f"fv_{i}"] = np.ravel(data)
```